# Problems compiling simple OpenCL example code under Xcode 6.1.1 with C++

Tags: c++, xcode, opencl

I have a simple hello world OpenCL program. For some reason the compiler gives an error when I try to reference the kernel name from within the code.

In kernel.cl I have

```
kernel void square_kernel(global float *input, global float * output, const unsigned int count)
{
    size_t i = get_global_id(0);
    if(i<count)
        output[i] = input[i] * input[i];
}
```

In main.cpp I have:

```
...
#include "kernel.cl.h"
...
int main()
{
    ...
    dispatch_sync(queue, ^{
        size_t wgs;
        gcl_get_kernel_block_workgroup_info(square_kernel, CL_KERNEL_WORK_GROUP_SIZE, sizeof(wgs), &wgs, NULL);

        cl_ndrange range = {
            1, // number of dims
            {0, 0, 0}, // offset in each dim
            {DATA_SIZE, 0, 0}, // global range (total)
            {wgs, 0, 0} // local size of each work group #work_groups = DATA_SIZE  / wgs    
        };

        // call kernel
        square_kernel(&range, (cl_float *)mem_in, (cl_float *)mem_out, DATA_SIZE);

        // copy the output
        gcl_memcpy(results, mem_out, sizeof(cl_float) * DATA_SIZE);

    });
    ...
}
```

I get "use of undeclared identifier square_kernel" where it is referenced. The cl file must be building because it generates the byte code files.

Now its just occurred to me that it might be because I am referencing it from a c++ file. However I am not sure how to fix that problem, if that is what causes it. I don't want to use C if I can help it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's worth checking the auto-generated `kernel.cl.h` header to double-check the definition of the function you are trying to call in this situation. I've just created a new Xcode project and built your OpenCL kernel with it, and the resulting function definition looks like this:

```
extern void (^square_kernel_kernel)(const cl_ndrange *ndrange, cl_float* input, cl_float* output, cl_uint count);
```

Note the extra `_kernel` in the function name.

Comment: Interesting the extra "_kernel" added. Not very intuitive.

Comment: Where do I find the kernel.cl.h file? I was looking around for that but I could not see it.

Comment: OK I just found it, its under Interemediates/opencltest.build/Debug/opencltest.build / DerivedSources